# Jquery-sortable not displaying red arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/ for my table in order to drag and sort elements.
But I am having a problem displaying the red arrow head when I start to drag an item.  The red arrow seems like it is missing...does anyone here know how to display it?

Here is the JavaScript code I've tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sorted_table').sortable({
            containerSelector: 'table',
            itemPath: '> tbody',
            itemSelector: 'tr',
            placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>'
        });
});
```

Here is the associated html:

```
<table id="listOfFile" class="table table-hover sorted_table">
                    <thead class="head">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="filename">File name</td>
                            <td class="type">Type</td>
                            <td class="detail">Details</td>
                            <td class="status">Status</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="body">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to add styles .... something like this:

```css
 /** Define arrowhead **/
.sorted_table tr.placeholder:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    top: -4px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: red;
    border-right: none;
}
```